# Hibernate loading children of a parent on user click?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

Here is my hibernate POJO classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class Parent {

  @Id
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
  private List<Child> children;

  // Getters and Setters...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child {

  @Id
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", nullable = false)
  private Parent parent;

  // Getters and Setters...
}
```

Here are two ways, from what I've learned about hibernate. (I'm still noob :P)

```
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  List<Child> children = null;

  try {
     children = session.createCriteria(Child.class, "C")
                  .add(Restrictions.eq("C.parent", parent)
                  .list();
  } finally {
    session.close();
  }
```

Or

```
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  List<Child> children = null;

  try {
     session.refresh(parent);
     children = parent.getChildren();
  } finally {
    session.close();
  }
```

The later one which is using refresh, I found out accidentally while experimenting with Hibernate.

Q.1 What is the best way?

Q.2 Why use Criteria API or HQL to get lazy load members, when you can get all children just by calling the getter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load children by calling getter method only if the parent object is attached to session. You can attach an object to session through either loading it (what calling `refresh` does on above code) or saving or updating; see documentation for more explanation. Like following code:

```
Session s = getSession();
Parent parent = s.get(parent, id);
List children = parent.getChildren();
```

And doing this basically is same as using criteria API (the way you have used). Criteria and HQL are used for a big variety of other things. In your case there is no point on using them.

Comment: And also, I have an doubt! Am I using refresh() method for wrong purpose, Is it used for different purpose? So, can I use this approach for production use?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh(java.lang.Object)) for refresh documentation. You are using it right. And yes this approach can be used for production absolutely (unless you have long-running sessions as it has been mentioned in documentation which you shouldn't use refresh in this case).

Comment: Ok, My session begins when creating the swing GUI for Parent with its children and closed when it has completed the GUI, before setting the frame to be visible. Will it be called a long running session?